# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\sum.php on line 52

Tags: php

```
<?php

 echo '<body style="background-color:046C33">';


 echo '<body style="background-color:orange">';

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("customers") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" >
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<tr>ENTER NIC NUMBER
<td><input type="text" name="query" id="text" />&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="search" value="Search" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$query = $_POST['query']; 
$min_length = 1;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
{ 
$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); 
echo "<table border='0' width='' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>";
echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='62E15E'> 

<td height='35px' width='150px'>NAME</td> <td>NIC NUMBER</td><td>GVS AC/NUM</td><td>DUE DATE</td><td>AMNT</td><td>DUE</td>
<td>DUE BALANCE</td><td>PAYMNET MONTH</td><td>AMOUNT</td><td>INTERST</td><td bgColor=red colSpan=0>SHORT</td><td>OTHER CHRG</td>
<td>DELAY CHRG</td><td>ADVANCE</td><td>TOTAL DEDEC</td><td>BALANCE</td></tr>"; 



$raw_results =
```

> mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pay_detec WHERE (`nic_num` LIKE
>   '%".$query."%') OR (`cust_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')");
>
> ```
> $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
> $totals = array();
>
> if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
> {
> while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
> { 
>
> foreach ($data as $item){
>   $totals[$item['cust_name']] = isset($totals[$item['cust_name']]) ? $totals[$item['cust_name']] + $item['payment'] : $item['payment'];
> }
>
> foreach ($totals as $payment => $val){
>   echo $payment.': '.$val;
>   echo "\n\n";
> }
> ```

```
echo "<tr align='CENTER' bgcolor='FBE946'>

<td height='25px'>".$results['cust_name']."</td> <td>".$results['nic_num']."</td><td>".$results['acc_num']."</td><td>".$results['due_date']."</td>
<td>".$results['loan']."</td><td>".$results['due_months']."</td> <td>".$results['blanc_due']."</td><td>".$results['month_pay']."</td>
<td>".$results['payment']."</td><td>".$results['INTRST']."<td bgColor=red colSpan=0>".$results['short']."</td><td>".$results['othr_chrg']."</td><td>".$results['DELAY_CHRG']."</td><td>".$results['ADVNC']."</td><td>".$results['ttl']."</td><td>".$results['blanc2']."</td></tr>" ;
}

}
else{ 
echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#6C0000'>

<td colspan='2' height='25px'>No results</td><tr>"; 
echo "</table>"; 
} 
}
else{ 
echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;

 }
}
echo "<a href='index.html'>HOME PAGE</a>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you doing, and trying to achieve? What is line 52? Also note that mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: how to i solved this problem my php code not work i shown this problem

Comment: line 52 is   $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

Comment: I think it's better to explain your problem and just show the lines where the error comes from. What is $this in this context?

Comment: $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

Comment: Does $sql even exist? And $this->db ?

Comment: below i shown my full code can you check that  pls

Comment: It's very hard to read your code in the current format.

Comment: how can i send that clearly

Comment: Right now it contains lines which probably aren't in your real code.

Comment: i added again can you check out now

Comment: yeah its not my own code please help me

Comment: Then why not ask the person who made this to fix it? This whole line doesn't make sense in your code $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

Comment: no i just follow this lines in stack overflow users answer

Comment: @pushparajha jeevanesan How have you instantiated your DB Class that you are referring to? Also what is this "answer" in stack overflow that you refer to? You are just slapping code together from anywhere, in a rather bad way here.

Comment: i just include that code to middle of that script i don't know correct one  whats the correct script

Comment: i accept your answer but i still stuck my problem is how to count displayed column values in table i want to add the sum code to below i shown code can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to stop using mysql_ functions and start using PDO.
In this case the line `$data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();` doesn't make any sense.

This piece of code is wrong and should be changed:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pay_detec WHERE (nic_num LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (cust_name LIKE '%".$query."%')");

$data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
$totals = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
{
```

It should be something like this:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pay_detec WHERE (nic_num LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (cust_name LIKE '%".$query."%')");
$data = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);

if(count($data) > 0) {
```

Note that this is not tested, but I hope this will guide you in the right direction.
Please have a look at some PDO tutorials since this code is absolutely not safe.

Comment: i accept your answer but i still stuck my problem is how to count displayed column values in table i want to add the sum code  to below i shown code can you please help me

Comment: Yeah, well, I highly recommend you to first do some tutorials in PHP. Again you have some variables which make absolutely no sense here. Just copying some scripts from other people doesn't make your code work, since they probably use other variables. Do you even know how your script works?

Comment: no i just  include 4 line only others. %like% comparison is working i need particular id values only count. how can do that?

Comment: below code work i just included                                                         $data = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
$totals = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
{
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{ 

foreach ($data as $item){
  $totals[$item['cust_name']] = isset($totals[$item['cust_name']]) ? $totals[$item['cust_name']] + $item['payment'] : $item['payment'];
}

foreach ($totals as $payment => $val){
  echo $payment.': '.$val;
  echo "\n\n";
}                  this only

Comment: Like I explained earlier; $this->db->query($sql) doesn't fit in your code.

Comment: yeah i understand i asking have any other idea

Comment: how to sum table data value in php

Comment: That is another question, and has nothing to do with this thread.

Comment: exactly i need sum table data i haven't any idea that's why i try that wrong code